# KeyError after adding a variable to the linopy model with define_variables

Tags: pypsa

I'm learning how to use Pypsa and I am not very experienced in python. My current goal is to understand how the optimization problem works (using Cplex solver) and I was trying to add a new variable and constraints with the compact module, but any variable I add to the model with new names get the same error:

```
return getattr(self, self.components[component_name]["list_name"] + "_t")

KeyError: 'Name_of_the_variable_I_add'
```

At the moment, my solution was to use an existing name and instead add a new attr like this:

```
pypsa.optimization.compat.define_variables(n, lb, ub, name="Generator", attr='new_attr', axes=[n.snapshots, n.generators.index])
```

The optimization find the solution. As far as I understand, in the components.py file the value for the new variable cannot be stored as the list of pypsa names do not have the new variable I am adding. There must be a problem as the example from the documentation declare a new name for a new variable... so I gues it works.

I hope someone can help me figuring out what I am doing wrong. This is also my first time using stackoverflow, apologise for any mistake in posting the question.

Comment: How do you try to access the variables?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer, but I don't try to access the variable. I get the error every time I declare a new variable.

Comment: Maybe I found the reason.

When trying to run the example from the documentation under the API reference of  pypsa.linopt.define_variables, I get a KeyError; this happen because PYPSA, specifically in assign_solution() located in optimize.py, it extracts all variable names and then attempts to save the values into n.components[component_name]["list_name"]. 

Am I correct in my understanding?